# Graphing modes of BJT

Tags: voltage, transistors, current, bjt

Suppose we have this Ic vs Vce graph of a BJT transistor

[image]

I have been taught this graph is applicable for this BJT transistor configuration.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRJvw2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If we instead had the circuit below, how would the graph change? (If it changes at all.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feUvtr.png)</sup>

Comment: The graph shows the first quadrant (positive \$V_{CE}\$ and positive \$I_C\$ for several positive and discrete values of \$I_B\$. It does not matter how the BJT is put in this condition (where are the resistors, current/voltage sources). BTW: why the inverted current arrows?

Comment: @devnull ah yes sorry.

Comment: This is one of those moments where the best thing to do is to **not** give you the answer.  Ask yourself what should happen, then use the simulator built into the schematic editor you used to draw your circuit examples and see what happens.  See if it matches your expectations.  If it doesn't match, figure out where your expectations were wrong.  Once you know what effect the circuit change has, you can post your results as an answer to your own question.

Comment: I can use Multisim ,put a variable current source (from 20uA to 120uA) to the base of the BJT and use the built-in oscilloscope by connecting the 2 probes the red probe to the collector and the black proble to the emitter.

Comment: *"I can use Multisim [...] "* Note that the base current varies with just a few discrete values while the voltage varies as a "DC sweep". Check how to do this an build a single graph with your simulator. Unless you are talking about the DC Load Line, but it doesn't look like it from the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this type of graph the DC load line extents are based on two conditions, when the collector-emitter junction is an open circuit, and when it is a short circuit.

The point where the DC load line meets the X axis is based on the collector-emitter voltage and collector current when the transistor is considered as an open circuit.

The point where the DC load line meets the Y axis is based on the collector current and collector-emitter voltage when the transistor is considered as a short circuit.

Doing a DC circuit analysis under these two conditions will get you the values for these points, a line drawn from one point to the other will then give you all of the possible values for conditions where the collector-emitter is somewhere between open and shorted. When adding in the emitter resistor you just do the DC analysis with it included. The characteristic curves showing I<sub>C</sub> vs. I<sub>B</sub> at V<sub>CE</sub> are largely based on the transistor's beta along with a few other factors, the resistors in the circuit will not change those but you need to make sure they line up with the X and Y axes correctly.

You should be able to do this with pencil and paper, draw the circuit out and do the analysis for each condition.

In the real world the transistor is never going to be completely open or shorted, there will always be a bit of leakage and there is a minimum value for Vce, but it gets you close enough for most purposes. There is also an AC load line that takes the AC impedances in the load and emitter bypassing into account.